# How to have a single export name (environment based) for multiple key-value exports in zsh?

Tags: amazon-web-services, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

I'm using zsh and have my aws env exports in zshrc file as bellow:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_Development = 1234
export AWS_SECRET_Development = 1234

export AWS_ACCESS_Production = 1234
export AWS_SECRET_Production = 1234
```

I need to have multiple environments so i can easily use only the environment name instead of all KEY-SECRET when i run commands for different environments like:

```
ENV-1:
export AWS_ACCESS_Development = 1234
export AWS_SECRET_Development = 1234

ENV-2:
export AWS_ACCESS_Development = 1234
export AWS_SECRET_Development = 1234
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but the syntax is not exactly handsome.

In a general programming language, you would have the environments modelled as an associative array, where the keys are the environment id's (in your case ENV-1, ENV-2), and the values are again associative arrays, where the key is either ACCESS or SECRET, and the value the respective development number.

AFIK, Zsh does not provide nested associative arrays (at least not in version 5.5.1 which I am using), but you can replace one of level of the arrays by indirect variable name references.

Assume that you define your environments as associative arrays

```
 declare -A env1 env2
 env1=( [ACCESS]=1234 [SECRET]=2345 )
 env2=( [ACCESS]=3456 [SECRET]=4567 )
```

Use a variable `env` as a general environment accessor. If you know that you are in environment 1, set

```
 env=env1
```

You can then access the SECRET value for this (for example) by

```
 secret_development=${${(P)env}[SECRET]}
```

where the `(P)` cares for the indirection. It is tempting to add for better legibility some white space in this expansion expression, but don't do this. The expression will become invalid.